# iOS-Charts - Graph incomplete due to missing data

Tags: ios, graph, ios-charts

I am working on getting multiple line charts displaying on the same graph. The problem is, when there are missing data points, the graph doesn't fill in gaps. Is there a way for it to automatically do this?

[image]
[image]

The first and second images show the same graph, only a slightly different frame for the x-axis. Has anyone else run into this same problem? I believe the problem stems from lacking enough data points. The graph displays accurately when zoomed out, but runs into this problem when I zoom between two known data points where no data point is present. The solution I'm currently exploring is to interpret the slope between points and fabricate data points for the missing x-axis points. This process is quite extensive and seems a little impractical. Does anyone have a better solution for this?

Comment: Hey @Jeff, can you please share your dataSet to make incomplete graph for missing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines fill based on having adequate data. The standard for these charts is to be undefined where there is no Y value present. If you were to fill in more data, your graph would maintain its continuity.